# Why mciSendString cannot open my mp3 file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mp3, mci

I am trying to play MP3 audio in C++ Visual Studio 17.3.0, but keep getting `MCIERROR` 275 followed by 263.

My `.mp3` file is in the same directory as my `.cpp` file.

My code goes something like this:

```
MCIERROR me = mciSendString(TEXT("open ""Music.mp3"" type mpegvideo alias mp3"), NULL, 0, NULL);
while(true){
    me = mciSendString(TEXT("play mp3"), NULL, 0, NULL);
}
```

Have tried different `.mp3` files, different directory, and different function for playing the sound (`PlaySound()`), which gave me a very similar result/error.

What could be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Unlikely that the executables working directory is the same as your .cpp file is placed. Try a full path 1st.

Comment: just tried that, got a different first error: 259, MCIERR_UNRECOGNIZED_KEYWORD

Comment: Any spaces in paths?

Comment: actually yes, how am I supposed to treat spaces on paths?

Comment: Enclose the whole path in `"` double quotes. Note that you need to escape these in string literals: `"\"c\\dir xy\\file.mp3\""`

Comment: I added this fix and now I am getting "some" sound, similar to windows error sound, but not my actual audio file

Comment: @LuisMoita change `"open ""Music.mp3"" type mpegvideo alias mp3"` to `"open \"Music.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3"`.  The former is concatenating multiple string literals into a single string `"open Music.mp3 type mpegvideo alias mp3"`

Comment: Did this issue help you?  If your case has been solved, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: It didn't work, I am almost sure the problem isn't in the code itself as I have tried multiple solutions. What worked for me in the end was converting my mp3 to wav and using the PlaySound function.  That said I am marking this question as solved since there is no visible solution for my problem and I am awarding @YujianYao-MSFT for the best answer in hope that someone with a similar problem could find a solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is to open:

```
mciSendString("open Summer.mp3 alias song",NULL,0,NULL)
```

Add the relative path or absolute path of the file after open (depending on the relative position of the music you play and your program)

We could understand alias as replacing your music name with the name after alias, which is convenient for us to carry out subsequent operations, only need to enter your alternative name (to save the trouble if the song name is long)

The last three parameters can be written as I do, because we are just simply playing music, so there is no need to go into details.

Next is to play:

```
mciSendString("play song repeat",NULL,0,NULL);
```

play+music name (or an alternative name after alias)+[play selection]

Playback options include repeat, wait.

repeat means to repeat the song.

wait means that the function does not return until the song has finished playing.